# AWS Rekognition call index-faces on all images in an S3 bucket instead of one by one?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-rekognition

I am testing Image Recognition from was. So far good. What I am having problems with is indexing faces in the CLI. I can index one at the time, but, I would like to tell AWS to index all faces in a bucket. To index a face one at the time I call this:

```
aws rekognition index-faces --image "S3Object={Bucket=bname,Name=123.jpg}" --collection-id "myCollection" --detection-attributes "ALL" --external-image-id "myImgID"
```

How do I tell it to index all images in the "name" bucket?

```
I tried this:
aws rekognition index-faces --image "S3Object={Bucket=bname}" --collection-id "myCollection" --detection-attributes "ALL" --external-image-id "myImgID"
```

no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You currently can't index multiple faces in one index-faces call. A script that calls get-objects on the bucket and then loops through the results would accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone in the future, I had a similar need, so I wrote this Python 3.6 script to do exactly what @chris-adzima recommends, and I executed it from a lambda function.

```
import boto3
import concurrent.futures

bucket_name = "MY_BUCKET_NAME"
collection_id = "MY_COLLECTION_ID"

rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)


def handle_image(key):
    rekognition.index_faces(
        CollectionId=collection_id,
        Image={
            'S3Object': {
                'Bucket': bucket_name,
                'Name': key
            }
        }
    )


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    pic_keys = [o.key for o in bucket.objects.all() if o.key.endswith('.png')]
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(handle_image, pic_keys)
```